# Excel VBA Select worksheets from a list where the value is TRUE

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to write a macro that will print some sheets to pdf.  I have a worksheet ("PDF") that lists all the worksheets in the workbook in column D and next to that in column F I have a list of TRUE/FALSE values.  My macro should print all the worksheets in column D that have a TRUE in column F into a single pdf file.

The number of sheets in this workbook does vary.

Below is my first stab at code for this

```
Sub PDFCreater()

Dim pdfName As String
Dim FullName As String
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim ArrSize As Integer
Dim ArrWkst As String
Dim RowCnt As Long, ArrCnt As Long

pdfName = Sheets("PDF").Range("D1").Text
FullName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & pdfName & ".pdf"

ReDim myArray(Sheets("PDF").Range("D2").Value)    'Size of array/ number of sheets in PDF
ArrCnt = 0
For RowCnt = 8 To 302
    If Sheets("PDF").Cells(RowCnt, 6).Value = True Then
        myArray(ArrCnt) = Cells(RowCnt, 4).Value
        ArrCnt = ArrCnt + 1
    End If
    RowCnt = RowCnt + 1
Next
'Select all worksheets in MyArray()
Sheets(myArray).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FullName _
, Quality:=xlQualityMedium, IncludeDocProperties:=False,
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description you have several errors in your code

```
Sub Test()
Dim pdfName As String
Dim FullName As String
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim ArrSize As Integer
Dim ArrWkst As String
Dim RowCnt As Long, ArrCnt As Long

    pdfName = Sheets("PDF").Range("D1").Text
    FullName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & pdfName & ".pdf"

    ' You need to re-dim the array in the loop in order to have an array with
    ' the correct dimension. Otherwisae the array is too big and will contain
    ' empty entries
    'ReDim myArray(Sheets("PDF").Range("D2").Value)    'Size of array/ number of sheets in PDF
    ArrCnt = 0
    For RowCnt = 8 To 302
        If Sheets("PDF").Cells(RowCnt, 6).Value Then
            ReDim Preserve myArray(ArrCnt)
            myArray(ArrCnt) = Cells(RowCnt, 4).Value
            ArrCnt = ArrCnt + 1
        End If
        ' the for loop will increase rowcnt itself
        ' no need to do that
        'RowCnt = RowCnt + 1
    Next
    'Select all worksheets in MyArray()
    Sheets(myArray).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FullName, _
                                    IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the loop to Hide the Sheets with a FALSE value, then:

```
ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FullName _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

This will save the whole workbook as PDF with the exception of the hidden sheets.